Declaring a variable as potentially not defined in a TypeScript declaration
Say I’m trying to use the MyAwesomeLib library in a TypeScript project. The way MyAwesomeLib works is that you load it with a <script async> tag, then access it from the global scope as myAwesomeLib (or window.myAwesomeLib).
Because my project is written in TypeScript, I’m writing a .d.ts declaration file for the library. I’ve got something like this:
interface MyAwesomeLib {
  // function declarations and whatnot here
}

declare var myAwesomeLib: MyAwesomeLib;

However, because MyAwesomeLib is loaded with a <script> tag, there’s a chance that my code could run before it’s loaded. If that happens, then the myAwesomeLib global won’t be defined yet, and accessing it would throw a ReferenceError. Therefore, I need to be sure to first check with either typeof myAwesomeLib !== 'undefined' or window.myAwesomeLib !== undefined.
How can I get the TypeScript compiler to require me to add that check?
Failure #1: Declare as undefined
This doesn’t work, because a variable that is not defined is not the same as one that contains undefined.
declare var myAwesomeLib: MyAwesomeLib | undefined;

// This code is allowed, but blows up at runtime
myAwesomeLib?.doSomething();

Failure #2: Window global
This feels closer, but makes it impossible to access myAwesomeLib as a global.
declare global {
  interface Window {
    myAwesomeLib?: MyAwesomeLib;
  }
}

// This code is no longer allowed
if (typeof myAwesomeLib !== 'undefined')


This is programming. Either, it works, or it doesn't. There is no such thing as a "maybe" state, or if it does, consider switching language.

Well just don't use <script async> for libraries. Either use ES modules with proper import declarations, or use <script defer> as "Scripts with the defer attribute will execute in the order in which they appear in the document." (MDN) so you control the execution order and run your application code after the library.

This isn't possible in TS; there's no "possibly undeclared" status for global variables. It looks like TS would prefer you do what you call "failure" #2: access it on window (and then you can save it to a local if you want).  There's a longstanding open feature request at ms/TS#14306 asking for some way to warn on globals (mostly stuff in the DOM), but most of the arguments there are for pushing people to use window, so we're back to failure #2. Does this fully address the question? If so I'll write an answer; if not, what's missing?

@NVRM JavaScript is far from the only language with race conditions

@Ryan That's right. However, this is a high level language, things like race conditions are handled at a system level, just not worry about that. Now, our code must not look like: if maybe (this).then(do maybe(that)), it might look handy, but it will quickly become a non debug able mess :)

Still waiting for a reply to this comment so we know how to proceed here.

@jcalz Unless someone comes up with a solution, this seems like the closest thing to an answer I’ll get
